# I want a symbol to be automatically converted to an expression on input but not on output

Tags: evaluation

I want the symbol `j` to automatically convert to `{-1,1}` on input, but when seen in output stay intact. What can I do for that?

I tried

`j={-1,1}`

and

`j:={-1,1}`

but in both cases the conversion happens both at input and at output.

Comment: Mathematica will keep rewriting as long as there are downvalues for `j`. Could you please add a minimal example of where you wanted to hold `j` but it got evaluated to `{-1,1}`?

Comment: @Syed I just do not want intervals in output at all. Maybe I should use output weights?

Comment: This depends on the operations performed with `j` during your calculations. For example, if in the output it is always met in the form `{-1,1}` it is obvious that you can use the rule `{-1,1}->j`.  This, I believe, you know without me. On the other hand, it is not difficult to imagine an example, where it is impossible to make any replacement of this kind. Therefore, it is important to see a minimal example of your expression.